# Adding Extra info to <select> form element

Tags: forms, email, jquery-selectors

I really hope you can assist.   I am trying to develop a small costing page, you can see it at http://impakt.co.za/QUOTE/email.html   the front end is working ok I guess, but, when the form submits to me,   the actual selected dropdown name/description isnt passed.

ie: ill get "  Jumping Castle: 395  "  in the email, where ideally would love to get the actual item selected.

Unfortunately this is above my understanding.

I hope you can shed some light or point me in the right direction.

Comment: What did you try to do so far? Can you give some code examples?

Comment: oh dear, went off while typeing ...  Im really wondering if there is a way to append the <select? element, in order to add additional data, or else, possibly creating an array of options per <select? line.   This function is working by using the <value> option within the <select? form element ... it uses that to do the calculating or the amount.

Comment: one thought I had (just a theory) - was to try add additional value (like a SUM option), & try have that keep the maths component, then use the <value> field as my normal email drop down select.

I have no idea though, how to make this system look for a  <sum> field. 

Im happy to send all my code to you if it helps